# How can I remove check for user data (invalid token error)

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, security-token

I've found a lot of advice on how to keep [invalid token] error from occurring.  I've tried them and still have an issue.  I just want to get rid of the check.  Can anyone tell me off hand where I would go to remove the check from the system completely?  Hopefully it's in a template somewhere so I can just make an override.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The tokens in Joomla are super important from a security perspective in forms to stop people from cross site scripting attacks - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

I strongly strongly advise not removing them under any circumstance. It's not in a controller tho.

As for the check itself the check is made in the controller for example here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.3.6/components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php#L26 and would be super hard to override I'm afraid. You'd pretty much have to override (maybe with a plugin on onBeforeRender) every single controller including 3rd party ones.